# How to show the fetch content from upstream?

Tags: git

How to check the git fetch's content?

I want use `git fetch & git rebase` to merge the content of upstream.

after I exec git fetch:

```
$ git fetch upstream 
From github.com:kubernetes/kubernetes
 * [new branch]              feature-rate-limiting    -> upstream/feature-rate-limiting
 * [new branch]              feature-serverside-apply -> upstream/feature-serverside-apply
 * [new branch]              feature-workload-ga      -> upstream/feature-workload-ga
 * [new branch]              master                   -> upstream/master
 * [new branch]              release-0.10             -> upstream/release-0.10
 * [new branch]              release-0.12             -> upstream/release-0.12
 * [new branch]              release-0.13             -> upstream/release-0.13
 * [new branch]              release-0.14             -> upstream/release-0.14
 * [new branch]              release-0.15             -> upstream/release-0.15
 * [new branch]              release-0.16             -> upstream/release-0.16
 * [new branch]              release-0.17             -> upstream/release-0.17
 * [new branch]              release-0.18             -> upstream/release-0.18
 * [new branch]              release-0.19             -> upstream/release-0.19
 * [new branch]              release-0.20             -> upstream/release-0.20
 * [new branch]              release-0.21             -> upstream/release-0.21
 * [new branch]              release-0.4              -> upstream/release-0.4
 * [new branch]              release-0.5              -> upstream/release-0.5
 * [new branch]              release-0.6              -> upstream/release-0.6
 * [new branch]              release-0.7              -> upstream/release-0.7
 * [new branch]              release-0.8              -> upstream/release-0.8
 * [new branch]              release-0.9              -> upstream/release-0.9
 * [new branch]              release-1.0              -> upstream/release-1.0
 * [new branch]              release-1.1              -> upstream/release-1.1
 * [new branch]              release-1.10             -> upstream/release-1.10
 * [new branch]              release-1.11             -> upstream/release-1.11
 * [new branch]              release-1.12             -> upstream/release-1.12
 * [new branch]              release-1.13             -> upstream/release-1.13
 * [new branch]              release-1.14             -> upstream/release-1.14
 * [new branch]              release-1.15             -> upstream/release-1.15
 * [new branch]              release-1.16             -> upstream/release-1.16
 * [new branch]              release-1.17             -> upstream/release-1.17
 * [new branch]              release-1.18             -> upstream/release-1.18
 * [new branch]              release-1.19             -> upstream/release-1.19
 * [new branch]              release-1.2              -> upstream/release-1.2
 * [new branch]              release-1.20             -> upstream/release-1.20
 * [new branch]              release-1.21             -> upstream/release-1.21
 * [new branch]              release-1.22             -> upstream/release-1.22
 * [new branch]              release-1.3              -> upstream/release-1.3
 * [new branch]              release-1.4              -> upstream/release-1.4
 * [new branch]              release-1.5              -> upstream/release-1.5
 * [new branch]              release-1.6              -> upstream/release-1.6
 * [new branch]              release-1.6.3            -> upstream/release-1.6.3
 * [new branch]              release-1.7              -> upstream/release-1.7
 * [new branch]              release-1.8              -> upstream/release-1.8
 * [new branch]              release-1.9              -> upstream/release-1.9
```

I have two questions about this:

1. why it display so many branches? and when I show branch of my local/repo, there only display master:

```
$ git branch
* master
```

2.how can I display the fetched content from upstream I have not rebased?

Comment: 1) Because there are new branches in your remote repository and `git fetch` tries to fetch all updates? If I'm not mistaken, since I use no-args `git fetch`, `git fetch <REMOTE|REPO_URL> <REFSPEC>` can fetch specific refs only (say, the `master` branch only). `git branch` only shows your local branches, unless at least `-a` or `-r` are added to the command.

Comment: 2) Probably by using `git diff @..@{U}` or `git diff @{U}..@` comparing local branch and its upstream counter-part to inspect it quickly. Or anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. why it display so many branches?

Because that's how many got made on the remote since you last fetched.
And it seems they're using branches instead of tags for releases.

They are all stored in your repository as "remote tracking branches". These are just like regular branches, but you don't commit to them. They track a branch on the remote. Each remote tracking branch is prefixed with the name of the remote.

```
* [new branch]              feature-workload-ga      -> upstream/feature-workload-ga
```

This tells you that upstream added a new branch called feature-workload-ga and you are tracking it as upstream/feature-workload-ga.

> and when I show branch of my local/repo, there only display master

By default, `git branch` only shows your local branches. To see the remote tracking branches, upstream/whatever, use `git branch -r`. `git branch -a` shows all branches.

See [Remote Branches](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) in Pro Git for more.

> 2.how can I display the fetched content from upstream I have not rebased?

Assuming you want to see a diff of your master vs upstream/master you can do `git diff master..upstream/master`.

Answer (score 0):

- these branches are stored in your repo as remote branches, you can list them using :

  ```
  git branch -r
  ```
- since your active local branch is `master`, you probably want to inspect the remote `upstream/master` branch :

  ```
  git diff master upstream/master
  git log --oneline --graph master upstream/master
  ```

---

Using `git diff`, the 3 dots notation will show you the modifications the second branch since it "forked" from the first one :

```
# diff on 'upstream/master' since it forked from 'master' :
git diff master...upstream/master

# diff on your local 'master' branch since it forked from 'upstream/master' :
git diff upstream/master...master
```

The "fork point" is the commit that git would use as a merge base. Quoting [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-emgitdiffemltoptionsgtltcommitgtltcommitgt--ltpathgt82308203) :

> `git diff A...B` is equivalent to `git diff $(git merge-base A B) B`.

---

Using `git log`, the 3 dots notation will list the commits on *both* branches since the merge base. Add `--boundary` to also view the merge base in the graph :

```
git log --oneline --graph --boundary master...upstream/master
```